# Google URLShortener API returns ipRefererBlocked

Tags: php, google-api

I'm trying to use the Google URL shortener API with PHP:

```
$apiKey = 'ABC';
$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/';

$postData = array('longUrl' => $url);
$jsonData = json_encode($postData);

$curlObj = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=' . $apiKey);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8","Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"));
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

$result = curl_exec($curlObj);
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "usageLimits",
            "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
            "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
            "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
      }],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
}
```

I've checked the following:

- That the referers are set (both http and https)
- That the API console registers all of the requests, but sadly as "client errors" and not as "success"

The script is triggered whenever a user visits the page.

I really appreciate any tip that helps me past this annoying problem. I don't seem to find any solution "out there".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah, I know. The problem is that I've already registered the IP making the call and still getting this error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an app settings issue in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project). On the credentials screen it lists the IPs that are allowed to use the API Key. It's a security precaution to help protect the key if it leaks.

[image]

You need to edit allowed IPs to either be empty (less secure) or update it to include the actual IP of your server.

[image]

Comment: I've registered the server's IP address, but the question is, when a user visits the page and the page makes the request to Google API, is it the server's IP that's making the request (I bet on this one) or is it the user's? I can't figure out why the API woun't accept the IP number provided. Is there a log that displays what IP numbers that's trying to make the requests?

Comment: You are using PHP which is server side so it's the servers IP.

Comment: Well, this might be one of the most awkward moments ever. I've registered our MySql server's IP number and not our webserver's. Sorry for taking up your time and thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Those mistakes happen to the best of us.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add to this that I had a similar issue when using a Google API from a Rackspace cloud server. If ANY IP addresses are added, then it will always be blocked (checked multiple times to ensure it was the correct IP, including making requests from server to a page that reported the remote IP). So from Rackspace cloud hosts, I have to allow any IP. If I'm hosting anywhere else, then the IP restrictions work as designed.

Comment: I had the same problem from a server in OVH