# Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referrer restrictions.Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have to try get google calander events through javascript.

in google console, I create a project, API Key, OAuth client id and enable API for Google Calendar.

I have set Authorized javascript origin as http://localhost.

```
gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false }, handleAuthResult);
```

two days before working fine but yesterday it didn't worked and sohwing the below error.

> The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client
>   is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referrer
>   restrictions.

Error Message Are

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=698394884872"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions."
 }
}
```

Comment: so ... is the request specifying a referrer? Check in the **developer** tools network tab, look at the request headers to see if there is a Referer header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google URLShortener API returns ipRefererBlocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123516/google-urlshortener-api-returns-iprefererblocked)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem when hitting a YouTube API through postman.

**Url** -

```
 https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=H61xC_BUros&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&key=
```

**Error faced** -

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "usageLimits",
                "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
                "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions.",
                "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=292824132082"
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referrer restrictions."
    }
}
```

**Working Solution** -

Add the following **(in headers when hitting through postman)**

```
Referer : https://explorer.apis.google.com
```